# Is there a difference between Null, (Null) and Nothing in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

My apologies if this is a very easy question.

So In SSRS you can choose either (Null) from a drop-down , or Null, or use an expression with VBs Nothing keyword.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a test case. Create a parameter called "TestParam" with three possible values:

- `(Null)` (The prefilled available value)
- An expression set to `=nothing`
- Typing "Null" into the value box (as shown in the screen shot.)

The parameter must be set to allow null values to save the first of these.

Then created a dataset:

```
SELECT
   "Valid Row Returned"
WHERE
   @TestParam IS NULL
```

This returned a row if the parameter was set to the prefilled `(Null)` **or** `=nothing`. It did **not** return a row if the parameter was set to "Null" as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @Jamie F. I've just tested this myself and aggree. Well done!